# all possible combinations of bits given n max length and a known count of 1 bits

Tags: math, combinations, bit

I'm attempting to roll my own compression algorithm as an experiment. For part of my solution I need to count the number of 1 bits in the input bytes. Input bytes are currently required to be 8 bytes or 64 bits long. This would imply that I could have a count of 1 bits from zero up to 64.

What I'm struggling to understand and calculate is the max number of combinations I might run into with this approach?

**Example 1:**

1 bits count = 1
this would imply that there are 63 zero bits
meaning there are 64 total combinations in this scenario

**What I'm not understanding**

What happens when there are 32 one bits? My approach so far was simply multiplication: so for 32 one bits and 32 zero bits (remember we have a 64 bit max) so 64 x 32 = 2048.

Is this math correct?

This honestly seems too low but I'm just not sure. What's further confusing about this is how the fact that I know the number of 1's and zeroes but not their exact position, how that reduces the max possible combinations. Clearly if this was a simple how many total combinations are in 64 bits, that would be 2^64, which is a huge number. Giving me the doubt that my previous math is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way). You have 64 positions and want to choose 32 of them to place the 1 bits. The choices cannot have any repetition, and the order of the choices does not matter. That makes it a combinations problem.

The answer is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) of 64 over 32, which can be calculated by the formula

```
64! / (32! * (64-32)!)
```

where the exclamation point is the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

The calculated result is

```
1832624140942590534
```

which is much larger than your attempted answer.

For just one bit, the result is binomial 64 over 1, which indeed is 64, so you got that right. There are many packages in many computer languages that can calculate binomial coefficients.

Note that this is more of a mathematics question than a programming one. Since this does come directly from a programming issue, I did not just direct you to the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but in the future you should ask such questions there.

Comment: is this answer still true when considering that I need to actually re-create the original input, so not that i care what order they are actually in as we only have zeroes or ones, but I do need to replicate the original input of zeroes and ones through my other computations. one of those computations involves iterating over and guessing until we find the right answer (I have a way to verify during decompression the answer is correct with the given input). does this makes sense?

Comment: re-read your post several times and i think you've covered this completely. thanks again for the help and i apologize for not realizing math stack exchange existed.

Comment: @Vance: I'm afraid your first comment does not make sense to me, so I can't answer that question.

Comment: no worries, it does read a little gibberish atm. thanks again!